# Find most recent distinct records and sort by created_at in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I thought this would be pretty easy to find a solution to, but I can't find a question that matches what I'm trying to do.

Here's what I would like to see (this query does not work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (conversation_id) 
  *
FROM messages
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

In other words, return the full rows with the most recent created_at dates where conversation_id is distinct, and then order by created_at DESC.

I wrote a query below that does exactly what I'm looking for but I think I overcomplicated it. I also assumed that the most recent record would have the highest ID and ordered by that in the sub query instead of "created_at" (it returns the same order as created_at DESC but is less reader friendly).

```
SELECT 
  m.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (conversation_id) conversation_id,
    id
  FROM messages
  ORDER BY conversation_id, id DESC
) as t
INNER JOIN messages as m
  ON t.id = m.id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

Any help at making a simpler version of this query would be great.

---

**Example added for clarification**

If the messages table looks like this:

```
id, conversation_id, created_at, subject
1, 2,  "2014-10-21 00:01:00", "subject 1"
2, 43, "2014-10-21 00:02:00", "subject 2"
3, 12, "2014-10-21 00:03:00", "subject 3"
4, 2,  "2014-10-21 00:04:00", "subject 4"
5, 43, "2014-10-21 00:05:00", "subject 5"
```

Query should return the following:

```
id, conversation_id, created_at, subject
5, 43, "2014-10-21 00:05:00", "subject 5"
4, 2,  "2014-10-21 00:04:00", "subject 4"
3, 12, "2014-10-21 00:03:00", "subject 3"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no need for the join:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (conversation_id) *
    from messages
    order by conversation_id, id desc
) t
order by id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> **The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).** The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

So if you use `DISTINCT ON (conversation_id)`, you should start `ORDER BY` clause with the same column.

Comment: Thanks for the input but I already got that. What I'm asking is, "Is there a simpler solution than the second query in my question above."

Comment: You want to partition by conversation_id, order by  created_at and then choose the ones were rank < 2? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @newUserNameHere, not clear what you want then. First query uses `ORDER BY created_at`, second one -- not.

Comment: Look at this query in that link. SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date
FROM
  (SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC, empno) AS pos
     FROM empsalary
  ) AS ss
WHERE pos < 3;

Comment: @vyegorov, I updated the question to make it more understandable and added an example. Sorting by ID in the subquery achieves the same thing as sorting by time created at as the messages with the highest created_at dates also have the larger IDs. This is best seen in the example. Hope that makes sense.